# How to adapt excel VBA code to PPT VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

What I want to do is to make VBA code which will hide and show individual series on a chart. I know how to write a VBA code in Excel, but do not know to rewrite the same code in PPT VBA.

I have this code in Excel VBA:

```
Sub FirstSer()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim ser As Series

'Retrieve our chart and seriescollection objects'
Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

'Set the first series line to be hidden'

With ser.Format.Line
    If .Visible = msoTrue Then
        .Visible = msoFalse
        ser.Name = vbNullString
    Else
        .Visible = msoTrue
        ser.Name = "First"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

How can I write the same code in PowerPoint VBA?
I tried to find solution in similar posts, but every post considers specific code which is hard for me to adapt to my code as I am new in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the **Excel** specific referencing of the Chart:

`Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart`

With a referencer to the right object in the **Powerpoint** presentation like this:

`Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart`

The rest of your code can stay as is.

On a side note:
VBA is VBA - There's no difference between PowerPoint VBA and Excel VBA.
Sure, in Excel you get some objects that are Excel specific, but there's no real differences in using VBA in one application or the other. You can easily use it to generate complete presentations from within an Excel file for example.